# ¿Como asigno un texto a un valor especifico de una combobox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo la siguiente combobox:

```
<select name="lineas">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Quiero reemplazar la palabra Saab que tiene valor 2 con otra palabra, lo estaba tratando así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('select[name="lineas"] option:2').text("reemplazo");

            });
            </script>
```

Pero no me resulta, como se puede hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes seleccionar la opcion con valor 2 de la misma forma que seleccionaste el select con nombre "lineas" asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

                $('select[name="lineas"] option[value="2"]').text("reemplazo");

            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="lineas">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Saludos con **JavaScript** podrias realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var miSelect = document.getElementsByName("lineas")[0] ;
miSelect.options[1].text = 'Nuevo Valor';
```

```html
<select name="lineas">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Lo que se hace primero es obtener el **select** y posteriormente mediante la posición del option lo cambio el contenido

**Actualizacion**

Bien investigando un poco como hacerlo mediante el **value** seria de la siguiente manera:

```js
var miSelect = document.getElementsByName("lineas")[0] ;
for(i=0; i<miSelect.length; i++){
  var option = miSelect[i];
  if(option.value == 2){
   option.text ='Nuevo Valor';  
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="lineas">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Lo primero que hago es  obtener el select me retorna un **Array** con dichos **option** esto lo recorro mediante el ciclo for y en un if hago la comparacion para encontrar el value deseado y posteriormente cambiar su valor.

Suerte..!!